# Angularjs ng-model nested inside ng-repeat updates all

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

This should be simple. For some reason, when using ng-model inside of ng-repeat it updates all ng-models inside that repeat loop.

Here's the code. Any ideas?
http://plnkr.co/edit/iAgrPwwBMilCyeReeLt9?p=info

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting!!!

Problem is that you are resetting row.field with an object from "$scope.columns"

in

```
<td>
  <select ng-model="row.field" ng-options="column.title for column in columns"></select>
</td>
```

Here, row.field is reset with an object from $scope.columns and if you change this object in one row, as the other rows also use the same object, they repeat the same value.

You can change this model to row.field.type as

```
<td>
    <select ng-model="row.field.type" ng-options="column.type as column.title for column in columns" ng-change="resetRow(row.field)"></select>
</td>
```

and define `$scope.resetRow` in your controller to reset other properties based on the field type.

Here is the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gttRk68Ufl2F7tvE5hFp?p=preview).

> *I would love to have a feature in ng-options to return a copy of
>   the object selected instead of the object reference to solve your problem though.*